# How to get a package from ubuntu 20.04 in ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: apt, themes, 21.10

I upgraded my computer to ubuntu 21.10. But i don't like the new icons in the yaru theme in 21.10.
So i would like to install the yaru-theme-icon from 20.04 by doing something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install yaru-theme-icon=20.04
```

but apt does not find it. How can I tell apt to search in focal's packages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't. Repositories are strictly prepared for a specific version of Ubuntu. `.deb` installation packages of a repo may install on a different distribution. But, that is not the aim. Thus not tested, nor guaranteed.

That was the general answer on your question how to get a package from an earlier Ubuntu version.

Your real problem concerns wanting the older icon theme. You can install that icon theme manually in a rather safe way, without overwriting system managed system files.

Download the `.deb`, then unpack it and manually copy the directory containing the icons to your personal `~/.local/share/icons` directory. (Create the directory if it does not yet exist.) When you log out and then back in, that icon theme will override the default one.

Eventually, you could edit the `index.theme` file to change the name, e.g. to "Yaru20" (and preferably also change the name of the directory). Then, you can switch back and forth between the old (now Yaru20) and the new theme (Yaru) using GNOME **Tweaks** (`gnome-tweaks`).